# How to bind fn + delete on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Eclipse Juno on MacBook air.

On most OS X apps, `fn + delete` deletes next character. But this doesn't work on my Eclipse installation. I tried to change key configuration, but `fn + delete` doesn't work on the dialog.

[image]

How can I bind `fn+delete` key here?

Comment: fn+delete works for me as you expect and like other apps do in Juno on Mac OS X.  I'm pretty sure this is default out of the box behavior.

Comment: @whiskeyspider I wish I can get it back